# KUbuntu 22.04 jammy host, Virtualbox 6.1.32 Windows guest: GUI freezes in both directions

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, freeze

I am running a windows guest in Virtual Box on Kubuntu 22.04 jammy with kernel 5.15.0-27-generic. From time to time I experience different kinds of freezes. Sometimes, when I am in the VM I can contiue to work in the VM, but can't select another window from the host. Sometimes, when I am outside of the VM I can continue to work in all windows of the host, but can't switch back to the guest. In all cases so far I was able to switch to the console (Ctrl-Alt-F2) and back to the GUI. The mouse continues to work.

Often the system went back to normal after waiting for a couple of seconds. But once, even waiting for 10 minutes, did not solve the problem and the poweroff via the CLI from the console helped: "VBoxManage controlvm  poweroff".

I had this problem also seldomly on KUbuntu 18.04. It was so rare that I did not bother. Now it is happening more often and I already tried to find a solution via Google.

I use "shared folders". Originally I thought this might be the reason, but even when I work purely in the guest without touching the shared folder sometimes freezes still happen.

I'd appreciate any hints!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the strong impression that copy and pasting between the windows VM and the linux host is a trigger.

The following sounds very relevant: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=99685 Windows freezes especially when copy/paste

Comment: I am certain now that copy and pasting is the trigger.

Comment: I've created the following bug ticket for virtualbox: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/21016